# Return Type for Async Method in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing a method to delete employees loan schedule.This means I have to delete the result set which is a list. I read that the **List.Clear()** can delete the list. I have a custom method **repository** from interface which is async and returns **IEnumerable** . The problem I have is the return type of the async method after deleting the list.The error is get is

> The type arguments for method 'Task.FromResult(TResult)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public Task<bool> DeleteEmployeeSchedule(string employeeId, string loantypecode)
{
 var scheduleList =    _repository.FindBy(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId && e.LoanTypeCode == loantypecode).Result.ToList();
 scheduleList.Clear()
 return  Task.FromResult();
}
```

Hi guys i changed the code again. This time the items in the list were not deleted. Does that mean RemoveAll() does not delete records from the database.The code below does not delete the records.

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteEmployeeSchedule(string employeeId, string loantypecode)
  {
    var scheduleList =    _repository.FindBy(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId && e.LoanTypeCode == loantypecode).Result.ToList();
    scheduleList.RemoveAll(employee => employee.EmployeeId == employeeId);
    await _repository.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return  true;
  }
```

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages. _The type arguments for method 'Task.FromResult(TResult)' cannot be inferred from the usage_ means that compiler can't inferre type arguments for method 'Task.FromResult(TResult)' from the usage.

Comment: Your `Task.FromResult()` has no argument, it must have argument of `bool` type. How can you return `bool` from the `scheduleList`?

Comment: `List.Clear()` will only clear the contents of the `List`. It does **not** delete the records from the source `_repository`. Your code is creating a new list and then clearing it, but it's not making any meaningful changes.

Comment: also, you said your `FindBy` method is async, but you run it syncronously. Why? And if you need to run it syncronously, why are you returning `Task<bool>` and not `bool` it self?

Comment: what about using removerange or remove all?

Comment: @lutakyn, could you please show your repository?

Comment: @lutakyn - If you're manipulating the `scheduleList` then you're doing nothing to the `_repository`.

Answer (score -2):

you have some syntax error, you are missing the parameters for `Task.FromResult();` passing in a boolean will answer your question.

change your line to:  `return Task.FromResult(true);` will fix your error message.

In addition you can refactor your call to use `await:

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteEmployeeSchedule(string employeeId, string loantypecode)
{
     var scheduleList = (await _repository.FindBy(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId && e.LoanTypeCode == loantypecode).ToList();

     scheduleList.Clear()

     //NOTE: however your error occurred on the line below due to wrong syntax, you have to pass in a boolean value eg. true/false
     return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

**EDIT**:
Without seeing more code, for example what datatype your `_repository` is and how it is implemented, we  have to assume too many things...
As in one of the comments stated, this will not persist in the database.

**EDIT2:**
@lutakyn posted following code changes as a comment 
(*please update your initial post with the updated code*)

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteEmployeeSchedule(string employeeId, string loantypecode) 
{
    var scheduleList = (await _repository.FindBy(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId && e.LoanTypeCode == loantypecode)).ToList();

    scheduleList.RemoveAll(employee => employee.EmployeeId == employeeId);
    await _repository.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return true;
}
```

the `scheduleList` contains the entities matching your criteria, removing them from that list or calling `.Clear()` will not affect the entities in your DbContext. You have to call on your DbContext the remove like:

```
_repository.DbContext.Schedule.RemoveRange(scheduleList);
```

However `.Schedule` is an assumption since we do not know how your _repository looks like, what datatype the `.DbContext` exactly is and what your `DbSet<>` is in your `DbContext` implementation.

Comment: "will indeed delete" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: @Enigmativity you cannot see the return type there is no guarantee that it is _System.Collections.Generic.List<T>_ it could, for what we know,be a custom class which persist changes on clear. We also do not know if the repository type is a custom implementation around DbContext or not..

Comment: @Tomek I bet the result is `IEnumerable<T>` and LINQ `.ToList()` extension is returning `List<T>`, so `Clear()` will do nothing.

Comment: @vasily.sib fair enough

Comment: @Tomek also, can you please add a corrected code (with `async/await`) from question in case if someone somehow will find this question in future?

Comment: public async Task<bool> DeleteEmployeeSchedule(string employeeId, string loantypecode)
      {
          var scheduleList =    _repository.FindBy(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId && e.LoanTypeCode == loantypecode).Result.ToList();

          scheduleList.RemoveAll(employee => employee.EmployeeId == employeeId);

          await _repository.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return  true;
      }

Comment: @lutakyn in your answer there are a few assumptions that _repository exposes EF's DbContext through a property DbContext. We do not know that without seeing at least a little bit more code.

Comment: @Tomek - If you were a betting man, what would you think the odds of it being anything other than `List<>`?

Comment: @Tomek, the a list of records are returns from the query but now it is not being saved. It seems RemoveAll does not delete records from database although SaveChangesAsync() is called. I am thing of using a transaction here.

Comment: @lutakyn because you just clearing a list, you have to call RemoveRange on your `DbContext`'s correct `DbSet<>` and then save the context.

Comment: @Enigmativity off topic..anyway, the provided answer solves the error message which was the question - however a second question arose which tackles obviously the persistence issue. And to provide solution that works for `lutakyn` we need a little more insight in his code.